# Train recurrent neural net in deeplearning4j with data that is generated during runtime

Tags: java, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, deeplearning4j

I'm new to the deeplearning4j library, but I've got some experience with neural networks in general.
I'm trying to train a recurrent neural network (a LSTM in particular) which is supposed to detect beats in music in realtime. All examples for using recurrent neural nets with deeplearning4j that I've found so far use a reader which reads the training data from a file. As I want to record music in realtime via a microphone, I can't read some pregenerated file, so the data which is fed into the neural network is generated in realtime by my application.

This is the code that I'm using to generate my network:

```
    NeuralNetConfiguration.ListBuilder builder = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT).iterations(1)
            .learningRate(0.1)
            .rmsDecay(0.95)
            .regularization(true)
            .l2(0.001)
            .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
            .updater(Updater.RMSPROP)
            .list();

    int nextIn = hiddenLayers.length > 0 ? hiddenLayers[0] : numOutputs;
    builder = builder.layer(0, new GravesLSTM.Builder().nIn(numInputs).nOut(nextIn).activation("softsign").build());

    for(int i = 0; i < hiddenLayers.length - 1; i++){
        nextIn = hiddenLayers[i + 1];
        builder = builder.layer(i + 1, new GravesLSTM.Builder().nIn(hiddenLayers[i]).nOut(nextIn).activation("softsign").build());
    }

    builder = builder.layer(hiddenLayers.length, new RnnOutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MCXENT).nIn(nextIn).nOut(numOutputs).activation("softsign").build());

    MultiLayerConfiguration conf = builder.backpropType(BackpropType.TruncatedBPTT).tBPTTForwardLength(DEFAULT_RECURRENCE_DEPTH).tBPTTBackwardLength(DEFAULT_RECURRENCE_DEPTH)
            .pretrain(false).backprop(true)
            .build();

    net = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
    net.init();
```

In this case I'm using about 700 inputs (which is mostly FFT-data of the recorded audio), 1 output (which is supposed to output a number between 0 [no beat] and 1 [beat]) and my hiddenLayers array consists of the ints {50, 25, 10}.

For getting the output of the network I'm using this code:

```
    double[] output = new double[]{net.rnnTimeStep(Nd4j.create(netInputData)).getDouble(0)};
```

where netInputData is the data I want to input into the network as a one-dimensional double array.
I'm relatively sure that this code is working fine, since I get some output for an untrained network which looks [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XdB0.png) when I plot it.
However, once I try to train a network (even if I train it just for a short time, which should alter the weights of the network just a little bit, so that the output should be very similar to the untrained network), I get an output which [looks like a constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ei6d.png).

This is the code which I'm using to train the network:

```
    for(int timestep = 0; timestep < trainingData.length - DEFAULT_RECURRENCE_DEPTH; timestep++){
        INDArray inputDataArray = Nd4j.create(new int[]{1, numInputs, DEFAULT_RECURRENCE_DEPTH},'f');
        for(int inputPos = 0; inputPos < trainingData[timestep].length; inputPos++)
            for(int inputTimeWindowPos = 0; inputTimeWindowPos < DEFAULT_RECURRENCE_DEPTH; inputTimeWindowPos++)
                inputDataArray.putScalar(new int[]{0, inputPos, inputTimeWindowPos}, trainingData[timestep + inputTimeWindowPos][inputPos]);

        INDArray desiredOutputDataArray = Nd4j.create(new int[]{1, numOutputs, DEFAULT_RECURRENCE_DEPTH},'f');
        for(int outputPos = 0; outputPos < desiredOutputData[timestep].length; outputPos++)
            for(int inputTimeWindowPos = 0; inputTimeWindowPos < DEFAULT_RECURRENCE_DEPTH; inputTimeWindowPos++)
                desiredOutputDataArray.putScalar(new int[]{0, outputPos, inputTimeWindowPos}, desiredOutputData[timestep + inputTimeWindowPos][outputPos]);

        net.fit(new DataSet(inputDataArray, desiredOutputDataArray));
    }
```

Once again, I've got my data for the input and for the desired output as a double array. This time the two arrays are two-dimensional. The first index represents the time (where index 0 is the first audio data of the recorded audio) and the second index represents the input (or respectively the desired output) for this time step.
Given the shown output after training a network, I tend to think that there must be something wrong with my code used for creating the INDArrays from my data. Am I missing some important step for initializing these arrays or did I mess up the order I need to put my data into these arrays?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: excellent question. please join the community on gitter. https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j committers on the channel will be able to help you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but perhaps 99.99% of your training examples are 0, with only an occasional 1 exactly where the beat occurs.   This might be too imbalanced to learn.  Good luck.